# How do i access a function in a component with a button in a different component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using [react-timer-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timer-hook) to set up a stopwatch for my React Application. So I got a Timer.js file where this stopwatch is working with a start and pause button. I am calling the component in App.js so the timer shows up on all pages. My next step is to set up that start functionality in a different component named Start.js (and later on the pause in the final page), but I can't figure out how I can pass it to this component.

This is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Timer/>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={ <Start /> }></Route>
            // Other routes
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Timer.js file:

```
function MyTimer({ expiryTimestamp }) {
  const {
    seconds,
    minutes,
    start,
    pause,
  } = useStopwatch({ expiryTimestamp, onExpire: () => console.warn('onExpire called') });


  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <div className='timer-inside' >
        <span>{minutes < '10' ? '0' + minutes : minutes}</span>:<span>{seconds < '10' ? '0' + seconds : seconds}</span>
      </div>
      <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyTimer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So basically i want the `<button onClick={start}>Start</button>` snippet to work in a file called Start.js, instead of the Timer.js itself.

Comment: where will you be consuming the `start.js` component? Will it be the child of `Timer` component? Or the child of `App`?

Comment: The Start.js will be a child of App.js. Timer.js is also a child of App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the Start component as a children of Timer, you can pass the start function received from the useStopwatch hook like

```
<Start onClick={start} />
```

And inside the Start

```
<button onClick={onClick}>Start</button>
```

But, if you want to render it on App, you need to call the hook on App and pass what you need on the components you need:

```js
function App() {
  const timer = useStopwatch({ onExpire: () => console.warn('onExpire called') });

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Timer data={timer} />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={ <Start data={timer} /> } />
            // Other routes
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So in both components will have same data property.

Hope it helps!